# Angular 4 & Material Stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Is it possible to reset (or just jump to the first step) inside of a  [stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview)?
It is not documented in the docs, but is it possible to do so?
It is stated in the docs that the stepper is built on "CDK Stepper" ([link](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/stepper/stepper.ts)?), but I can't find any examples which lead me to my goal.

Comment: @Edric why do you keep removing the `angular-material2` tag? \o/

Comment: @Faisal Just wondering but is there any difference between [tag:angular-material] and [tag:angular-material2]?

Comment: there is not imo, but most of the users post questions using `angular-material2` tag. I think we should create a this tag as synonym of `angular-material`. I will propose that once I have enough score in that tag.

Comment: @Faisal Actually, it's been asked two times. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349630/yet-more-angular-tag-madness-this-time-about-angular-material and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346111/synonyms-angular2-material-and-angular-material2

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ok, it seems I found a solution (but it is not stated anywhere on the API).

1. Add a reference to the stepper, then add `ViewChild` with the reference in your component typescript file.
2. Create a method to change the index of the stepper.

HTML:

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
    <!-- Content here -->
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

TS:

```ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    // ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('stepper') stepper;

    /**
     * Changes the step to the index specified
     * @param {number} index The index of the step
     */
    changeStep(index: number) {
        this.stepper.selectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seemed too good to be true. I am getting an error when using this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined
    at MdVerticalStepper.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/esm5/stepper.es5.js.CdkStepper._anyControlsInvalid (stepper.es5.js:351)` Anybody know why?

Comment: You may use `this.stepper.reset()` instead. See the `MatStepper` documentation at https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api

Comment: `this.stepper.selectedIndex` don't get updated the first time. You need to call it twice to move to `next` step.  Is you aware of it ? @Ben jamin

Answer (score 18):

> It is possible to jump to a specific stepper. **`MatStepper`** exposes a
>   public property **`selectedIndex`** which specifies the currently selected
>   step index. It can be set. The index starts at 0.

**In your template:**

Add an id to your stepper e.g. **`#stepper`**. Then add a button in your step, and pass the stepper id in a function on **`(click)`** like below:

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
    <!-- Your other steps here -->
    <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
        <!-- Content in the step -->
        <div>
            <!-- Other actions here -->                 
            <button mat-button (click)="resetStepper(stepper)">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>
    <!-- More steps here -->
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**.. and in your typescript:**

```ts
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material';

exported YourOwnComponent {

  constructor() {}

  resetStepper(stepper: MatStepper){
     stepper.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

[**Stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-g7uncw?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: 43mins too late :) thanks anyway, its always good to have a working demo like yours to demonstrate a solution

Comment: Okay, the "reset" seems to work just partial, if you want to reset also the form, it cleans out the values but the form stays invalid.
I forked your demo here to demonstatrate the demo (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-2upkqd?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: not sure why that is happening even after form reset \o/

Comment: seems like a bug, i also thought to overwhelm this bug i could also reload the current view, but this also seems to be problematic ...

Comment: Here the completed steps icons is set to "EDIT" and the current steps icon is set to "NUMBER" can I have the completed steps icon as "DONE(tick)" and when back button pressed the completed step icon changed to "Edit"....EX: assume I completed step 2 and clicked on next button now the step 2's icon showing as "EDIT icon(pen symbol)" and now I am in step 3 which shows "Number" as icon....What I want to do is the When next btn clicked from step 2 the icon should be "DONE" and 3rd step icon should be "Number",if I clicked back btn of 3rd step the icon of 3rd step should be "DONE" 2nd is "EDIT"

Comment: Brother ,looking for your response @Faisal

Comment: @Zhu i'll try to respond you as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks brother I’m waiting for your solution for my request.@Faisal

Comment: @Faisal,Bro can you help me by today ,I tried to solve but I need someone's help to completed this coz I am new to Angular

Answer (score 3):

In the html template , reference your stepper with  **#stepper**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

and in your typescript file declare the stepper

```
@ViewChild("stepper", { static: false }) stepper: MatStepper;
```

after that you can set the stepper step with his selectedIndex property

```
 this.stepper.selectedIndex = 0; //0 is the index of the first step
```